# SujetaTypeExenta obsoleto en SII versión 1.1

Tags: vb.net, aeat-sii

En la versión 1.0 de SII, para comunicar facturas emitidas sujetas a IVA pero exentas por tratarse de exportación a un pais comunitario, empleábamos el siguiente código para definir el TipoDesglose:

```
    Dim retval As New FacturaExpedidaTypeTipoDesglose
    retval.Item = New TipoConDesgloseType
    retval.Item.Entrega = New TipoSinDesgloseType
    retval.Item.Entrega.Sujeta = New SujetaType
    retval.Item.Entrega.Sujeta.Exenta = New SoapFacturasEmitidas.SujetaTypeExenta
    retval.Item.Entrega.Sujeta.Exenta.BaseImponible = "123.45"
    retval.Item.Entrega.Sujeta.Exenta.CausaExencion = "E5"
```

Al migrar a la versión 1.1, el webservice ya no reconoce el tipo **SujetaTypeExenta**.

La documentación menciona el nuevo tipo DetalleExentaType pero al ponerlo en lugar de SujetaTypeExtensa provoca un error:

> retval.Item.Entrega.Sujeta.Exenta = New
>   SoapFacturasEmitidas.DetalleExentaType
>
> Method invocation failed because 'Public Property Exenta() As AeatSii.SoapFacturasEmitidas.DetalleExentaType()' cannot be called with these arguments: Argument matching parameter 'Value' cannot convert from 'DetalleExentaType' to 'DetalleExentaType()'.

Comment: A mi no me ha tocado nunca pegarme con SII, pero revisando un poco el esquema, existe `DetalleExentaType`. Puede ser lo que buscas? De hecho, tiene dos propiedades por lo que veo, `BaseImponible` y `CausaExencion` asi que podría ser.

Comment: Es lo pimero que probé, pero si sustituyo SujetaType por DetalleExentaType me devuelve el siguiente error: Method invocation failed because 'Public Property Exenta() As AeatSii.SoapFacturasEmitidas.DetalleExentaType()' cannot be called with these arguments:
    Argument matching parameter 'Value' cannot convert from 'DetalleExentaType' to 'DetalleExentaType()'.

Comment: Matias, si has probado algo y te ha lanzado alguna excepción, no lo añadas en los comentarios. Pulsa en [edit]  y añade toda la información en la propia pregunta

Comment: Perdona la tardanza matias, pero primero tuve que convertir el esquema xsd a clases, luego probé el código en C# y finalmente convertirlo a vb.net. Espero que te sirva

Answer (score 1):

El error que te da es porque ahora `Exenta` es una lista, no un objeto. Con lo que tienes que añadir objetos `DetalleExtensaType` a la colección con `Add`. El código sería algo asi:

```
Dim retval As New FacturaExpedidaTypeTipoDesglose
retval.Item = New TipoConDesgloseType
retval.Item.Entrega = New TipoSinDesgloseType
retval.Item.Entrega.Sujeta = New SujetaType
retval.Item.Entrega.Sujeta.Exenta = New List(Of DetalleExentaType)
retval.Item.Entrega.Sujeta.Exenta.Add(New DetalleExentaType With {.BaseImponible = "123.45", .CausaExencion = CausaExencionType.E5})
```

Comentar que `CausaExencion` parece haber cambiado tambien, ya no es un string sino una enumeracion de tipo `CausaExencionType`.

Comment: Gracias Pikoh, vamos por buen camino. Pero el valor de retval.Item.Entrega.Sujeta.Exenta es Nothing cuando intentamos añadir el elemento a la colección, por lo que hay que llamar primero al constructor para generar una instancia de la colección. El problema es que ...Exenta = New DetalleExentaType() me da el error Method invocation failed because 'Public Property Exenta() As AeatSii.SoapFacturasEmitidas.DetalleExentaType()' cannot be called with these arguments:
    Argument matching parameter 'Value' cannot convert from 'DetalleExentaType' to 'DetalleExentaType()'.

Comment: @MatiasMasso Eso que comentas en mi caso, al haber generado las clases haciendo uso del xsd no es necesario ya que al crear un nuevo `SujetaType` ya se inicializa `Exenta`. Ya que en el webservice por lo que comentas no es así, habrá que inicializarlo manualmente con `retval.Item.Entrega.Sujeta.Exenta = New List(Of DetalleExentaType)`. He editado la respuesta para hacerlo, ya me dices si funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Completando la propuesta de Pikoh, lo suyo es instanciar primero una lista del tipo DetalleExentaType, instanciar el DetalleExentaType, añadirlo a la lista y asignarla a la propiedad Exenta una vez convertida en Array:

```
Dim retval As New FacturaExpedidaTypeTipoDesglose
retval.Item = New TipoConDesgloseType
retval.Item.Entrega = New TipoSinDesgloseType
retval.Item.Entrega.Sujeta = New SujetaType
Dim oExentas as new list(Of DetalleExentaType)
oExentas.add(New DetalleExentaType With {.BaseImponible = "123.45", .CausaExencion = CausaExencionType.E5})
retval.Item.Sujeta.Exenta = oExentas.toArray
```

Comment: Yo no se si se debería hacerlo asi, ya que estas creando un array con un solo elemento y entiendo que es posible que en las causas de exección sean varias. Prueba con una lista como te pongo en mi respuesta editada.

Comment: El problema de la lista es que da un error de conversión al asignarla a la propiedad Exenta que espera un Array. Pero podemos emplear .toArray para convertirla. He editado mi respuesta en consecuencia

Comment: Bueno, obviamente nuestra definición de clases es diferente, ya que a mi si me admite una lista. Pero si lo has solucionado asi, perfecto.